# randomly replacing percentage of values per group with NA in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, random, replace, na

I have a dataframe with different groups (ID) of varying size. Within each group, I would like to randomly replace a specific percentage of values in the "value" column (let's say 30%) with NA's. Here is a simplified version of my data:

```
ID<-rep(c("X1","X2"),times=c(3,6))
value<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6)
df1 <- data.frame(ID,value)
df1
ID value
X1     1
X1     2
X1     3
X2     1
X2     2
X2     3
X2     4
X2     5
X2     6
```

Here is what I would like to have:

```
ID value
X1     1
X1     NA
X1     3
X2     1
X2     2
X2     NA
X2     4
X2     5
X2     NA
```

Any idea how I could do this? I have a preference for using tidyverse but if you have other options, that would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  Grouped by 'ID', get the index or 30% of the rows with `sample` and use that in `replace` to replace the 'value' with NA

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(value =  replace(value, sample(row_number(),  
           size = ceiling(0.3 * n()), replace = FALSE), NA) )
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
#  ID    value
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 X1       NA
#2 X1        2
#3 X1        3
#4 X2       NA
#5 X2        2
#6 X2       NA
#7 X2        4
#8 X2        5
#9 X2        6
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble using your answer. when I run this code, I get the following error: "n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.". Any idea where this would come from?

Comment: @Cam Here, `n()` is used within `dplyr` syntax ie. in `mutate`.  Not sure how that error pop up?  Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: @Cam Your input code had some typos.  I just edited those in your post.  Can you test now

Comment: it's version 1.0.1! And I'll try testing it now .

Comment: @Cam Can you try on a fresh R session with only `dplyr` loaded and the dataset because I can't replicate this

Comment: yes, that was it! Starting a new session did the trick. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is in df

```r
df[sample(seq(nrow(df)), nrow(df) *0.3), "value"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sample()` to get random indexes of your data.

You could try this

```
df <- data.frame(ID = paste("X", 1:10),
                 value = rnorm(10))

fraction <- 0.30

df$value[sample(1:length(df$value), size = round(length(df$value) * fraction))] <- NA

#30% of the values in df$value will then be NA
```